# Are there any settings on my laptop that will tell my browser "I speak English"?

Tags: macos

I was using the Chrome browser which suddenly adds this annoying offer to translate, written in Chinese because I'm accessing the internet from Taiwan. The problem is that GoogaChrome is shooting itself in the foot by covering its own message about moving to the English version of the site with it's offer to translate *in situ*.

Are there any settings in macOS that are somehow read by Chrome that will convince it to just go ahead and take me to the English version of the site, or am I completely misunderstanding how the internet works?

[image: Google/Chrome mess]

Comment: Google offers option to change language on it's home page. Login with Google, change Default language to English and select Translate from there.

Comment: @Pratik thanks for that! I do most of my browsing intentionally logged out, but it's a good to remember that being logged in has several advantages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may not be your best option as websites will often use your public IP address to *assume* your location, and that process is independent of both your browser and operating system.

If this is something that annoys you often enough you may be better to use a VPN service to make it appear as you're in the US, Canada, UK, Australia, etc (as they're natively English speaking locations).

If a VPN is not an option, then you could use something like the Opera browser instead which also includes its own VPN functionality. Of course, that is limited to Opera itself, and not your entire Mac (which may be either good or bad, depending on your requirements).

If you're bedded to using Google Chrome, then you could try and use the full macOS version of [TunnelBear](https://www.tunnelbear.com) which will camouflage all your internet traffic, or opt just for the [TunnelBear Chrome extension](https://www.tunnelbear.com/apps/browser) which only acts within Chrome itself. Either of these options will allow you to pick a geographical location that is predominantly English speaking.

If you opt for the Opera browser, it's entirely free. If you use either of the TunnelBear options, you get 500MB per month for free.

**NOTE:** I am not affiliated in any way with the Opera browser or TunnelBear.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks! I'd never heard of TunnelBear, but it looks like it addresses several inconveniences being overseas at once. I use Chrome because I'm used to it so I'll read up on Opera again, it's been quite a while (longer than I'll admit) since I've used it.

Comment: Isn’t spanish more common in the states now...